# How to wrap words of string every 1000 characters in php

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

i have some big string, and some array of words that must be replaced with some changes, like wrapping in link. First issue is wrap whole words or combinations words. And the second issue is do previous step minimum every 1000 characters.

```
$string="lalala word lalala blah, blah lalala combination of words lalala lalala...";  
$patterns=array('word','combination of words');  
$replacements=array('<a href="#">word</a>','<a href="#">combination of words</a>');
```

For an example, what i must to do with snippet before?

Comment: Guys, don't down vote unless you also can comment on why. @arsey, do you have any PHP programming skills? What code have  you tried?

Comment: yes i have some skills. i try this: preg_replace($patterns, $replacemants, $string);

Comment: @Steven: The down-arrow tooltip explains why downvotes are cast: "This question shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: for wrapping whole words i used '\b(word)\b', but it's not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
 <?php
        function set_keys_by_words($content, $key, $words,$before,$after) {
        $positions = array();
        $string = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {

            $string = preg_replace('/\b' . $words[$i] . '\b/ui', $key . $words[$i], $content);
            $position = mb_strpos($string, $key);

            if ($position != '') {
                $positions[(int) $position] = $words[$i];
            }
        }
        ksort($positions);
        $word = '';
        $number = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($positions as $k => $v) {
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1) {
                $number = $k;
                $word = $v;
            }
        }
        if ((int) $number) {
            $word_len = strlen($word);
            $part_after = preg_replace('/\b' . $word . '\b/ui', $before . $word . $after, mb_substr($content, 0, $number + $word_len));
            echo $part_after . mb_substr($content, $number + $word_len, 1000);
            $content = mb_substr($content, $number + $word_len + 1000);
            if ($content != '') {
                set_keys_by_words($content, $key, $words);
            }
        } else if ($number == '' && $content != '') {
            echo $content;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for [`wordwrap()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).  You can then use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to apply it to your search patterns and make the replacements:

```
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    $regex = '/' . preg_quote($pattern, '/') . '/';
    $string = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
        return '<a href="#">'
            . wordwrap(htmlspecialchars($match), 1000, '<br />')
            . '</a>';
    }, $string);
}
```